# Android .apk built from Unity3D 'App not installed' error on device

Tags: android, c, unity-game-engine

I searched around a lot before asking, on this website and others, I've found a lot of advice but I either can't fully understand it, or I'm implementing it wrong.
I build my .apk from Unity3D, and then I put that on Google Drive and using ASTRO File Manager on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (GT-P5110) I launch it and install it, it says 'installing' for a short amount of time and then it just tells me 'App not installed'.

Most of what I've read is telling me that it wont work if it's an unsigned build, but to start with I was using the debug option in Unity's Publishing Settings, and now I've generated a new keystore, rebuilt it, got it back over on the device and the same thing is still happening.

Am I missing some critical concept or step here? I'm brand new to Android development and it's taken me a while to get to this stage, so if there's something I'm missing that is glaringly obvious then please help me out!

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: Followed the instructions here, and it fixed my problem! Hope this helps someone else!

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/210920-Failure-INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR

The Solution in this is following:

1. Go to "Player Settings", click Android Tab
2. Under Other Settings/Configuation/Install Location, set to "Automatic".